# sed ranges aren't always able to match only one line

Tags: shell, sed

Consider the following range: `1,/pattern/`. If pattern matches on the first line, the range matches for the whole file:

```
$ cat 1.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
seq 1 4 | sed -rn '1,/'"$1"'/p'
$ ./1.sh 1
1
2
3
4
$ ./1.sh 2
1
2
```

What would you do about it?

**UPD** Here's what I did (just in case):

```
re='/1/'
seq 1 4 | sed -rn "1{$re{p;q}}; 1,${re}p"
```

Or this way:

```
seq 1 4 | sed -rn "1{/1/{p;q}}; 1,//p"
```

Comment: @mikeserv As to quoting, I tried to keep the script simple. Then, you can't expect the range to match only one line in this case, though it works with ranges like `1,1`. And the issue has nothing to do with general regexes. It's about matching only one line with `1,/pattern/` range. If you want to delete everything from the start of the file to some particular line, and that line happens to be the first one.

Comment: point taken. I specifically addressed how you might *delete everything from the start of the file to some particular line, and that line happens to be the first one* in the edit to my answer just now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's an annoying thing about `sed` (see the [`sed` FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html#s3.3) about that). Since you're using GNU `sed` (`-r` is GNU specific), you can do:

```
 sed -En "0,/$1/p"
```

(I prefer `-E` over `-r` as it's also supported by some other `sed`s like FreeBSDs and is consistent with `grep` and a few other tools (and is going to be in the [next issue of the POSIX/Single UNIX Specification standards](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528))).

A better alternative (and portable) would be:

```
sed "/$1/q"
```

To tell `sed` to quit (and stop reading) after the first match.

Note that `awk` doesn't have the issue so you can write:

```
PATTERN=$1 awk 'NR==1, $0 ~ ENVIRON["PATTERN"]'
```

(though like for `sed`, you'd rather write):

```
PATTERN=$1 awk '1; $0 ~ ENVIRON["PATTERN"] {exit}'
```

Comment: Minor improvement: The value passed to `awk` similarly needs quoting; or more simply use an `awk` variable not an env var `awk -vpat="$1" '1; $0~pat {exit}'`. And both `awk` methods work if $1 contains slashes, but to interpolate into `sed`'s argument you need `${1//\//\\\/}` (!).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, quoting is not needed in variable assignments (`PATTERN=$1`). The `-v` method has issues with backslashes (common in regexps) which using `ENVIRON["variable"]` doesn't have. Good point about the need to escape `/` in the `sed` variants.

Comment: For some reason, `man`, `info` and `sed` itself doesn't list `-E` as one of the options, but the option works. I'm running `GNU sed-4.2.1`.

Comment: @x-yuri, yes, it used to be there for portability with BSD but undocumented. Note that [-E is making its way into POSIX](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528), so GNU `sed` [is now documenting it](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/?id=8b65e07904384b529a464c89f3739d2e7e4d5135). I wonder what got into GNU sed authors head in the first place to pick `-r`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - do you know what happens when one of those bugs is marked accepted? Do you know what to expect from that point?

Comment: @mikeserv, I don't know much about how the austin group works. But given that that bug is tagged `issue8`, I'd assume it will be included in Issue 8.

Comment: Thank you. I also assumed that, I just didn't know if it was a sure thing, or if there were any real schedule for *when* issue 8 was due. There are some others there that are also interesting. Anyway, I thought if anybody would know - it would be you.

Comment: `mikeserv`'s idea of reversing the form is also a good one, I believe.

Comment: @x-yuri - it is nice to be appreciated. nicer still is to see my name immortalized as a shell command.

Answer (score 4):

It's normal behavior of `sed`. From POSIX [sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) documentation:

> Addresses in sed
>
> An address is either a decimal number that counts input lines
>   cumulatively across files, a '$' character that addresses the last
>   line of input, or a context address (which consists of a BRE, as
>   described in Regular Expressions in sed , preceded and followed by a
>   delimiter, usually a slash).
>
> An editing command with no addresses shall select every pattern space.
>
> An editing command with one address shall select each pattern space
>   that matches the address.
>
> **An editing command with two addresses shall select the inclusive range
>   from the first pattern space that matches the first address through
>   the next pattern space that matches the second**. (If the second address
>   is a number less than or equal to the line number first selected, only
>   one line shall be selected.) Starting at the first line following the
>   selected range, sed shall look again for the first address.
>   Thereafter, the process shall be repeated. Omitting either or both of
>   the address components in the following form produces undefined
>   results:
>
> [address[,address]]

You can see, `sed` will print the inclusive range from the first address through the next matched address.

In your case, `1,/1/p`, `sed` print the first line because it matches address `1`. Then from second line, sed will search for second address that matches pattern `/1/`. And stop print if found. Because from second line, you don't have any pattern that matches `/1/`, so `sed` print the rest.

In case with `1./2/p`, sed print the first line as above, then second line match pattern `/2/`, `sed` print it and repeat action for the rest. But You can not match address `1` for the rest, so `sed` does not print anything.

An example:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 1 4 1 | tr ' ' $'\n' | sed -rn '1,/1/p'
1
2
3
1
```

Because you use `GNU sed`, you can use form `0,addr2`:

```
0,addr2
              Start  out  in  "matched  first  address"  state, until addr2 is
              found.  This is similar to 1,addr2, except that if addr2 matches
              the very first line of input the 0,addr2 form will be at the end
              of its range, whereas the 1,addr2 form  will  still  be  at  the
              beginning of its range.  This works only when addr2 is a regular
              expression.
```

So, your command become:

```
seq 1 4 | tr ' ' $'\n' | sed -rn '0,/'"$1"'/p'
```

Then:

```
$ ./1.sh 1
1
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you can do. For instance, your comment indicates you mean to:

*...delete everything from the start of the file to some particular line, and that line happens to be the first one...*

You can do this like:

```
sed -n "/$1"'/,$p'
```

You just reverse the form. The above command will only print from some particular line til end of file.

If you want to not print that particular line...

```
sed -n "/$1"'/,$p' | sed 1d
```

...should do the trick...

Else you could just address the line and take the cycle into your own hands.

```
seq 20 | sed -ne"/$1"'/!d;:B' -e'n;p;bB'
seq 20 | sed -n "/$1"'/!d;h;n;G;P;D'
```

Both commands `d`elete every incoming line until encountering a `$1` pattern.

The first one then overwrites pattern-space with the `n`ext input line and sets up a `:b` label. It then `p`rints the line and overwrites pattern-space again with the `n`ext-line, before `b`ranching back to the `:b` label. It loops in this way until end of file. This command is probably faster than the second - it does less.

The second one overwrites `h`old-space with the `$1` match. It then also overwrites pattern-space with the `n`ext line on input. Next it `G`ets hold space and appends it the input line it just pulled in - thus reversing the order of the two lines and delimiting between them with a newline character. Something like:

- line 1 > hold space
- line 2 > line 1
- hold space >> line 2
- = line 2 \n line 1

At this point `sed` `P`rints only up to the first `\n`ewline character occurring in pattern-space and `D`eletes same before restarting the cycle with the remainder - which winds up *always* being the line that first matched `$1` for *every line*. So the first line matching `$1` is *always* in pattern-space but *never* printed.

And so if `$1` is `5` the following is printed:

```
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the `sed` range and do without the `-E` or `-r` option when you use a function list after the `sed` range containing the quit command `q` (tested with FreeBSD & GNU `sed`).

```
printf '%s\n' {1..10} | sed -n '1,/1/{p;q;}'

# your solution adapted to work with FreeBSD sed as well
re='/1/'
printf '%s\n' {1..4} | sed -En "1{$re{p;q;};}; 1,${re}p"
printf '%s\n' {1..4} | sed -En "1{/1/{p;q;};}; 1,//p"
```

Comment: The question isn't "How do I print the first line of a file?"; the question is "How do I print the first line of a file _through_ the first line that matches a pattern, even if that pattern occurs on the first line?" Your first answer prints only the first line, no matter what regular expression is used.